# parse strange Json response to a list

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to parse this object to a list of string. I do not need the key but just want the value as a list of string.

I cannot have a simple model classes because the keys object are more than 1000 in some responses and are random.

So please any idea how to parse it to list in kotlin or java?

```
{
    "data": {
        "21": "593754434425",
        "22": "4560864343802",
        "23": "7557134347529",
        "24": "5937544344255",
        "25": "45608643438024",
        "26": "75571343475293"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could first deserialize it as it is, and then convert to a list.

The JSON can be represented this way:

```kotlin
data class Response(val data: Map<String, String>)
```

You can mark this class `@Serializable` and use [Kotlinx Serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization) to deserialize it, or you can use other libraries like [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi) or Jackson (with [jackson-module-kotlin](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin)).

Once it's deserialized, simply get the values of the map (it's a collection):

```kotlin
val response = Json.decodeFromString<Response>(yourJsonString)

// this is a Collection, not List, but it should be good enough
val stringValues = response.data.values 

// if you really need a List<String>
val list = stringValues.toList()
```

If you want to get the values in the natural order of the keys, you can also use something like:

```kotlin
val values = response.data.toSortedMap(compareBy<String> { it.toInt() }).values
```

Comment: i have got the map but donot know about its keys thats where the problem starts... any idea..?

Comment: @AbbasKhanWaliullahi I thought you said the keys were random and you only cared about values. Do you mean you want the keys sorted?

Comment: The keys of a Map can be obtained used the Map::keySet method.  If you want them sorted.  Create a list from the key set and sort it.

Comment: @Joffrey No bro i just need the values and the keys are random

Comment: @AbbasKhanWaliullahi then what's wrong with my initial answer? Just use `response.data.values`

Comment: @Joffrey  with your answer it give me this error com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 11 path $.data[0]

Comment: Did you use the `Response` class as I provided in the answer? This class is never supposed to expect `BEGIN_ARRAY` at any point, so I don't think you actually used it, please double check.

Comment: i have used it like this in kotlin 
data class UnVerifiedTagIds(@SerializedName("data") val data: Map<String, String>)

Comment: (Off topic, but using Gson is usually a bad idea with Kotlin. It's not supported anymore and uses reflection in a way that can break Kotlin's nullability. You should instead at least use its successor Moshi, or some Kotlin-first libs like Kotlinx Serialization)

Comment: @Joffrey Okay let me do something about it, But thankyou man For your Help. StayBlessed...!

Comment: @AbbasKhanWaliullahi then either you're not deserializing this class, or you didn't recompile your code, or something. Because the error you get is when the data model expects a list or array but there is a String in the JSON. This could happen if you declared `Map<String, List<String>>` or something like that, but not if you expect `Map<String, String>`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to parse your data:

```
val it: Iterator<String> = json.keys()
val arrayList = ArrayList<String>()
while (it.hasNext()) {
    val key = it.next()
    arrayList.add(json.get(key))

}
```

A better way is to change the json model, if you access it.

```
{
    "data": [
        "593754434425","4560864343802",
        "7557134347529","5937544344255",
        "45608643438024","75571343475293"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, its handy to use the libriary [org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json).

See following code snippet:

```java
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Defining the input
        String input = "{\n" +
                "    \"data\": {\n" +
                "        \"21\": \"593754434425\",\n" +
                "        \"22\": \"4560864343802\",\n" +
                "        \"23\": \"7557134347529\",\n" +
                "        \"24\": \"5937544344255\",\n" +
                "        \"25\": \"45608643438024\",\n" +
                "        \"26\": \"75571343475293\"\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "}\n";
        // Parsing it to a json object with org.json
        JSONObject inputJson = new JSONObject(input);
        // If inputJson does not contain the key data, we return
        if(!inputJson.has("data")) return;
        // Else we read this data object to a new JSONObject
        JSONObject dataJson = inputJson.getJSONObject("data");
        // Define an array list where all the values will be contained
        ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
        // Get a key set of the dat json object. For each key we get its respective value and add it to our value array list
        for (String key : dataJson.keySet()) values.add(dataJson.getString(key));
        // Print all values
        for (String value : values) System.out.println(value);
    }
}

=>
4560864343802
7557134347529
5937544344255
45608643438024
75571343475293
593754434425
```

Installing org.json is the easiest with a package manager like [maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) or [gradle](https://gradle.org/guides/#getting-started).

Answer (score 0):

Guys i have comeup with a similar solution for the problem here
this is my model class

```
 data class UnVerifiedTagIds(

        @SerializedName("data")
        val data: Object

)
```

and this is how i parse the respone here

```
val values: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
   val list_of_tag_ids: ArrayList<String> =response.data as ArrayList<String>
```

Comment: What is `Object` here? `java.lang.Object`? This seems pretty unexpected in a Kotlin class, we prefer Kotlin's `Any` in general. Also, I don't think the JSON you provided can be deserialized into something that can be cast to `ArrayList`. Most likely JSON deserialization libraries will use some sort of map like `LinkedHashMap`, or use JSON-specific classes like `JSONObject`. Which library did you use?

Comment: yeah it is java.lang.Object i am not sure myself but it worked like a charm

Comment: The code in your answer contains a variable that serves no purpose. Could you please post the full code?

Answer (score 0):

The ist one is the dataclass for the response

and the 2nd one is the ApiCallInterface m using Retrofit...

and the last one is the apicall itself

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Please do not post screenshots of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). They are not searchable, nor copy-pastable for testing, nor accessible, and more. It is much more convenient if you embed code directly in the answer (add ``` before and after your code snippet).

Answer (score 0):

I am using Kotlin language
do class name with name like this `data class Result(val data:Map<String,String>)`
and using library GSON for convert string json to this model

```
  val json = "{\n" +
  "    \"data\": {\n" +
  "        \"21\": \"593754434425\",\n" +
  "        \"22\": \"4560864343802\",\n" +
  "        \"23\": \"7557134347529\",\n" +
  "        \"24\": \"5937544344255\",\n" +
  "        \"25\": \"45608643438024\",\n" +
  "        \"26\": \"75571343475293\"\n" +
  "    }\n" +
  "}"
val dat = Gson().fromJson(json,Result::class.java)
if (dat.data.isNotEmpty()){
val list= dat.data.values.toMutableList()
print(list)
}
```

that works fine with me